# Elasticsearch failed to start - CreateJavaVM Failed

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

sorry if this is a trivial question, but I've been banging my head against this and I'm getting nowhere, so I thought I'd throw it up.

I'm trying to install Elasticsearch on an Windows 2008 server on Azure. It appears to have installed correctly, but I cannot get it to start.

I have looked around for similar errors and double-checked my JAVA_HOME variable - it appears to be correct, as does the config file.

I also expanded out the heap size via editing the java options files, still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[Output Log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCU0q.png)

[JAVA_HOME variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG0mN.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Which version are you installing? The latest, which would be 5.5.0?
2. Which installation method did you use? The ZIP or the MSI file?

The last line in your *Output Log file* screenshot actually shows the error message: `The data area passed to a system call is too small.`

I'm taking a wild guess: You set `Java_HOME` in the user variables, but it **must** be set in the system variables.